# Start Powershell WinUserLanguageList from Service

Tags: windows-10, powershell, permissions, windows-services

There is a command needed to switch the user language. To run this script, it is done by a Windows Service. This service runs in System previleges.
Problem is, when the service starts the Powershell script, the user has no changed language. It seems to be, that the Powershell script needs to be started in user account as administrator.

Is there any solution how start the script with correct permission?

**keyboardFile.ps1**

```
# Remove old entries 
$LanguageList = Get-WinUserLanguageList 
$LanguageList.Remove($LanguageList[3]) 
$LanguageList.Remove($LanguageList[2]) 
$LanguageList.Remove($LanguageList[1]) 
$LanguageList.Remove($LanguageList[0]) 
# Add new entries 
$LanguageList.Add("%1") 
$LanguageList.Add("en-US") 
Set-WinUserLanguageList $LanguageList -Force
```

I started the script with a cmd batch file to start the ps1 keyboardFile:

**keyboardStart.cmd**

```
REM Execute Powershell script
powershell -executionpolicy bypass "& ""%keyboardFile%"""
PowerShell.exe -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%keyboardFile%""'}"
```

Comment: Why are you doing it as a System service? It would be much easier to run it as a logon script.

Comment: It is an existing environment. The system service is exisiting for this usage and required to use to change the keyboard setting. This service can only call a cmd file.

Comment: Is the service defined as interactive? In registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows`, is `NoInteractiveServices` defined as 0?

Comment: Good hint. By default this service is executing non-visual commands. So the environment is installed with this service by default. I can check this registry property. But anyway I am not able to change the service, just the batch. Your experience is, that after this property in registry its working proper?

Comment: It is required, but not sufficient by itself.

Comment: I checked. The value does not make changes regarding this execution.